# Can I change the page of a Custom Post Type slug?

Tags: custom-post-types

So I've created a simple custom post type for separating content in the back-end. The Custom Post Type has a slug and generates a URL using this slug, such as `www.yoursite.com/slug/`. Any pages made in the custom posttype will be `yoursite.com/slug/page-name`. This is correct, but now I wish to change the content of the page on `yoursite.com/slug/`. Everytime I visit this page it will redirect me to the homepage. Is there any way to change this?

I forgot to mention I've used the plugin CPT UI.
I found this code in CPT UI, not sure if it is of any use.

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_kennisbank() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Kennisbank.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Kennisbank", "blankslate" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Kennisbank", "blankslate" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Kennisbank", "blankslate" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "kennisbank", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "kennisbank", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_kennisbank' );
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you used to register your post type.

Comment: yes Milo is right you used register_post_type('example', $args); like this

Comment: Code? I used the plugin CPT UI.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to override /slug/? If so, you can just create a standard page title Slug and it will automatically create a post_name value of "slug" which should work fine to be at /slug/ (so long as your standard permalinks are %postname% or %category%/%postname%)

Comment: What I’d like to do is edit the page at /slug/ indeed, however there is not really a page I can edit anywhere. I havn’t tried creating a page with the same slug just yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom post types can have a post type archive, which displays all posts of that type. In your post type registration code, it's controlled by the `has_archive` argument, which is now currently `false`. Change it to `true`, or give it a string value to set it to something specific other than your post type slug.

```
"has_archive" => "kennisbank",
```

Comment: Thank you Milo! I've found that I could easily change this value in the CPT UI plugin by editing the current custom post type.